# Dissipating light pollution

Tags: visible-light, speed-of-light

If all the lights in a city, and the area surrounding it were shut off. How long would it take for the light pollution to clear, so the light from stars could be seen?

Comment: It depends on what your threshold for "cleared" is.  No doubt a few photons keep scattering around for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the high speed of light, the light pollution would clear, at least in a practical sense, almost instantaneously from the area once all lights were shut off.  One's eyes might need up to about 30 minutes to fully adjust to the dark, so it would take about that long for most of the stars to appear to "come out" to the naked eye.

Comment: Ahh, thank you, I didn't take into account our eyes adjusting to the darkness. This helps a lot.

Comment: No problem.  Welcome to Stack Exchange!